# Showing a Holomorphic $f$ has at most $4$ Zeros in the Unit Disc

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $D(0,N)$ denote the open ball in the complex plane centered at $0$ with radius $N$.
>   Let $f$ be holomorphic in $D(0,2)$ and continuous on its closure $\overline{D(0,2)}$. Suppose $\vert f(z)\vert \le 16$ for $z\in D(0,2)$ and $\vert f(0)\vert =1$. Prove that $f$ has at most $4$ zeros in $D(0,1)$.

I consider the function $h(z)=f(z)/(z+1)$, which is at most $16/2=8$ on the boundary of $D(0,2)$. $h$ is holomorphic because the singularity is removable, so by the Maximum Modulus Principle, $\vert h(z) \vert\le 8\vert z+1\vert$ in $D(0,2)$. I am not sure what I can conclude about the number of zeros of $h$ from here. I don't believe I have the correct approach, and I couldn't see how to apply Rouche's Theorem if that is indeed the way to go.

I am not sure if Schwarz's Lemma applies since $f(z)/z^4$ is not holomorphic in $D(0,2)$ due to the fact that the singularity at $0$ is not removable. How can I proceed?

Comment: What if you assume $f(z)=(z-a_1)(z-a_2)(z-a_3)(z-a_4)(z-a_5)g(z)$ for zeros $a_i$ inside the unit circle, and then work out the minimum possible distances to the boundary of a circle of radius 2.  For example, there must be a point $b$ such that $|b|=2$ and $|a_i-b|\geq 2$ for at least 3 of the zeros $a_i$ (but this observation is not strong enough, it would be strong enough if we were told $|f(z)|\leq 8$ for all $z \in D(0,2)$).

Comment: What does the existence of such a $b$ imply?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I was implicitly assuming $|g(b)|>1$, but all we know is $|g(0)|>1$.  So my comment above was not so helpful. The idea was $|f(b)|=|b-a_1||b-a_2|\cdots |b-a_5||g(b)|\leq 16$. If three of the $|b-a_i|$ terms are at least 2 (and the other two are at least 1), then we have $|f(b)|>8|g(b)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{z_1,\ldots,z_m\}$ be the multi-set of all roots of $f$ on $D(0,1)$ and
$$
h(z) = 2^m \prod_{k=1}^m\frac{z-z_k}{4-\overline{z_k} z}.
$$

Then $h$ is holomorphic on $\overline{D(0,2)}$, has roots exactly at $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ and $|h(z)|=1$ if $|z|=2$. So $f/h$ is holomorphic and by the maximum principle $|f/h| \leq 16$ on $D(0, 2)$.  At $z=0$ this inequality becomes
$$
\frac{1}{2^{-m} \prod_{k=1}^m|z_k|}\leq 16.
$$

Since $|z_k|<1$ it follows that $2^m < 16$ and $m\leq 3$. So $f$ has at most *three* roots on the open unit disc. Replacing $<$ by $\leq$ shows that it has at most four roots on the *closed* unit disc.